# Three dice are rolled simultaneously. In how many different ways can the sum of the numbers appearing on the top faces of the dice be $9$?

Tags: combinatorics, dice

> Three dice are rolled simultaneously. In how many different ways can the sum of the numbers appearing on the top faces of the dice be $9$?

What I did:
I know that the maximum value on the dice can be $6$. So, restricting the values of dice, $6-x+6-y+6-z=9$, $x+y+z=9$, $n=9$ and $r=3$.

Applying partition again:
$$\binom{9+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{11}2=55$$

But the answer is $25$. Please, someone explain this one.

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: This example is sufficiently small that it is easy to just write the $6$ posibilities down.
There are $\color{blue}{6}$ ways to roll $\{1,2,6 \}$,$\color{blue}{6}$ ways to roll $\{1,3,5 \}$,$\color{blue}{3}$ ways to roll $\{1,4,4 \}$,$\color{blue}{3}$ ways to roll $\{2,2,5 \}$,$\color{blue}{6}$ ways to roll $\{2,3,4 \}$,$\color{blue}{1}$ way to roll $\{3,3,3 \}$. So $\color{blue}{6+6+3+3+6+1}= \color{red}{25}$ ways (in toto).

Comment: what if there are 4 dices? so that is why i was asking about partition method @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
[x^\color{blue}{9}]:(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^\color{red}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
& get reduce or Wolfram alpha to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

In these types of problems, it is not too hard to just consider case by case. Let's list out all the possibilities and how many ways to reorganize them:
$$1,2,6 \rightarrow 3!=6 \text{ ways}$$
$$1,3,5 \rightarrow 3!=6 \text{ ways}$$
$$1,4,4 \rightarrow 3!/2!=3 \text{ ways}$$
$$2,2,5 \rightarrow 3!/2!=3 \text{ ways}$$
$$2,3,4 \rightarrow 3!=6 \text{ ways}$$
$$3,3,3 \rightarrow 3!/3!=1 \text{ way}$$
So in total there are $25$ ways to get a sum of $9$. If you want the probability, just take this over the total number of possibilities and you get $25/6^3 = 25/216$.

Answer (score 0):

What you did also counts solutions where $x,\,y,\,z$ can be $0$ as well, but that can't happen with dice.

You should do this for $$(x-1)+(y-1) + (z-1) = 9 -3,$$ i.e. $$x'+y'+z' =6$$ because it is now ok to have $x', y'$ or $z'$ to be $0$.

Now we get $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1} = 28.$ But, this is wrong as well, because $x',y',z'\leq 5$, so if we discard the three solutions where one of the $x', y', z'$ is equal to $6$, we get exactly $25$ ways.

Comment: But, this is wrong as well, because x−1,y−1,z−1≤5x−1,y−1,z−1≤5, so if we discard the three solutions where one of the x−1,y−1,z−1x−1,y−1,z−1 is equal to 66, we get exactly 2525 ways. @Ennar Didn't understand this part

Comment: @Cruzi Seku, we know that $x,y,z\leq 6$, so $x-1,y-1,z-1\leq 5$. But, writing $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}$ also counts solutions $(6,0,0)$, $(0,6,0)$, $(0,0,6)$ which can't happen with dice because there is no face with $7$ on it.

Comment: there is no face with 7 on it. I did not understand this part. But you said that solutions are (6,0,0),(0,6,0) and (0,0,6).Where is 7? @Ennar

Comment: Oh, ok, I haven't written it explicitly, sorry, I'm thinking of substitution $x' = x-1$, $y' = y-1$, $z' = z - 1$ and solutions of $x'+y'+z' = 6$. If, for example, we counted solution $(6,0,0)$ that would imply that $x = 7$. @Cruzi Seku.

Answer (score 0):

We must find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 9 \tag{1}$$
in the positive integers subject to the restrictions that $x_1, x_2, x_3 \leq 6$.

A particular solution of equation 1 in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of $3 - 1 = 2$ addition signs in the $9 - 1 = 8$ spaces between successive ones in a row of nine ones. 
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, placing addition signs in the third and seventh spaces yields
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 4$, $x_3 = 2$.

The number of solutions of equation 1 in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{9 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{8}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the eight spaces between successive ones to fill with addition signs.

However, we have included solutions in which some $x_i > 6$.  Since the summands are positive integers, this can only occur if one of the $x_i$'s is $7$ and the other two $x_i$'s are $1$.  There are three choices for which $x_i$ is equal to $7$.  Hence, the number of ways the sum of the numbers on the three dice could add up to $9$ is 
$$\binom{8}{2} - \binom{3}{1}$$

We can formalize the argument about the restrictions as follows.  Suppose $x_1 > 6$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 6$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 6$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 6 + x_2 + x_3 & = 9\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_2 & = 3 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{2}{2}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, the number of solutions of equation 1 in which $x_1 > 6$ is equal to the number of solutions in which $x_2 > 6$ and to the number of solutions in which $x_3 > 6$.  Hence, 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$
solutions of equation 1 violate the restrictions.  Therefore, the number of admissible solutions is 
$$\binom{8}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$